# Normalize a MySQL table having a redundant primary key

Tags: mysql, normalization, data-migration

I am working on upgrading the schema of a MySQL database that stores a list of **Persons and the Charities they are related to**. The table in question `Persons`, has a mix of personal data and associated charities. It has the following fields:

1. **Person_Id** (auto increment primary key)
2. **Citizen_Id** (a unique alphanumeric national id)
3. **Person_Full_Name** (self-explanatory)
4. **Person_Email** (self-explanatory)
5. **Person_Assistant_Contact** (the cellphone of the person's personal assistant)
6. **Charity_Org_Id** (foreign key for a master table of charitable organizations)
7. **Designation_Id** (foreign key for a master table of designations that the person can hold in the charitable organization)

Here is the DDL of the above if needed:

```
CREATE TABLE `Persons` (
    `Person_Id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `Citizen_Id` CHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE COMMENT 'a unique alphanumeric national id',
    `Person_Full_Name` CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `Person_Email` CHAR(50) NULL,
    `Person_Assistant_Contact` CHAR(20) NULL COMMENT 'the cellphone of the persons personal assistant',
    `Charity_Org_Id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key for a master table of charitable organizations',
    `Designation_Id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'foreign key for a master table of designations that the person can hold in the charitable organization',
    FOREIGN KEY (`Charity_Org_Id`) REFERENCES `Charity_Orgs` (`Charity_Org_Id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Designation_Id`) REFERENCES `Designations` (`Designation_Id`),    
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

As there are many persons who are part of multiple charitable organizations, the table has many entries where the name and contact info is the same, but Charity_Org_Id and Designation_Id are different. An example INSERT query (please note the first column and the last 2 columns):

```
INSERT INTO `Persons` VALUES
(2387,'OZN13445','Frederick Oznawa','info@oznawaind.org','+54-332887789',128,12),
(4533,'OZN13445','Frederick Oznawa','info@oznawaind.org','+54-332887789',520,2),
(4555,'OZN13445','Frederick Oznawa','info@oznawaind.org','+54-332887789',522,4);
```

The obvious step would be to separate the contact info and associated charities into separate tables. This is what I would want:

```
INSERT INTO `Persons` VALUES
(2387,'OZN13445','Frederick Oznawa','info@oznawaind.org','+54-332887789');

INSERT INTO `Person_Charities` VALUES
(2387,128,12),
(2387,520,2),
(2387,522,4);
```

Getting the new `Persons` table is simple. **I would want a pure SQL solution to get the 'Person_Charities' table** (I want to use the lowest Person_Id per person and discard the remaining Ids). I can do this manually using spreadsheet software but that is error prone and I am looking at thousands of rows.

*NOTE: I do not want to use the Citizen_Id as an alternative primary key*

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Yes, having separate `Persons` and `Person_Charities` tables sounds like a good idea.

Comment: What I want is a pure SQL solution to get data for the new `Person_Charities` table. I use SQL to migrate data from schema to schema

Comment: I assume that is a Dummy name and personal info you have in the INSERT statement.  If not please clean it up to no include someones personal info.

Comment: Absolute dummy data ... no worries there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the distinct list of the columns you are want to separate with the following query:

```
SELECT
    MIN(`Person_Id`) AS Person_Id
    `Citizen_Id`,
    `Person_Full_Name`,
    `Person_Email`,
    `Person_Assistant_Contact`
FROM
    Persons
GROUP BY
    `Citizen_Id`,
    `Person_Full_Name`,
    `Person_Email`,
    `Person_Assistant_Contact`assistant'
```

OK, we have a query to get the distinct list of the persons from your table.

**Create the new table**

You can either create a table with the [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) syntax, or you can create a new table to store the data and insert the distinct persons based on the above query using the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax. Personally I prefer to build a new table manually.

```
CREATE TABLE `New_Persons` (
  `Person_Id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `Citizen_Id` CHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE COMMENT 'a unique alphanumeric national id',
  `Person_Full_Name` CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `Person_Email` CHAR(50) NULL,
  `Person_Assistant_Contact` CHAR(20) NULL COMMENT 'the cellphone of the persons personal assistant'
);
```

**Inserting data into our brand new table**

```
INSERT INTO New_Persons (
  Person_Id,
  Citizen_Id,
  Person_Full_Name,
  Person_Email,
  Person_Assistant_Contact
)
SELECT
    MIN(Person_Id) AS Person_Id,
    Citizen_Id,
    Person_Full_Name,
    Person_Email,
    Person_Assistant_Contact
FROM
    Persons
GROUP BY
    Citizen_Id,
    Person_Full_Name,
    Person_Email,
    Person_Assistant_Contact;
```

Nice, we have a table with distinct persons. You can add additional constraints and indexes if you wish.

**How to continue?**

We have a table with the distinct persons (namely: `New_Persons`) and a table with the (nearly) similar person data in the original `Persons` table. The next step is to reduce the old `Persons` table to store only the required info.

The options are:

- Add a new column to store the id from the `New_Persons` table, then update that column with a [Multiple-table update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) query, then drop the unnecessary columns.
- Create a new table to store the calculated info, then drop the old table and rename the new tables.

If you have enough storage space, I recommend to use the second option. You can verify that the inserted data is OK or not, and you do not need to totally reorganize the old table. And the most important thing is that there is much less chance to loose any data (since you do not touch your existing table, so you can restart the process when something is wrong).

**Creating the new table**

```
CREATE TABLE `Person_Charities` (
  `Person_Id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
  `Charity_Org_Id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key for a master table of charitable organizations',
  `Designation_Id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'foreign key for a master table of designations that the person can hold in the charitable organization',
  PRIMARY KEY PK_PersonCharities (Person_Id, Charity_Org_Id)
);
```

Once again, you can adjust the keys, indexes and whatever you want.

**Inserting the data into our new table**

So, we have a new table which is empty, and two old tables which has some data and we know the relationship between them. Our goal is now to create a query to retrieve the new Person_id and the leftover columns from the old `Persons` table.

This sounds like a simple join on the given tables using the common columns except the `Person_Id`

```
INSERT INTO Person_Charities
(
  Person_Id,
  Charity_Org_Id,
  Designation_Id
)
SELECT
  NP.Person_Id,
  P.Charity_Org_Id,
  P.Designation_Id
FROM
  Persons P
  INNER JOIN New_Persons NP
    ON P.Citizen_Id = NP.Citizen_Id
      AND P.Person_Full_Name = NP.Person_Full_Name
      AND P.Person_Email = NP.Person_Email
      AND P.Person_Assistant_Contact = NP.Person_Assistant_Contact;
```

**Almost done**

Nice, we have the new tables with the data what we want, just their names are confusing :)

Rename the tables and we are done:

```
RENAME TABLE
  Persons TO Old_Persons,
  New_Persons TO Persons
```

**Sidenotes**

- In the original shema `Citizen_Id` is unique, but you are inserting duplicates. Either the schema or the inserted data are wrong.
- You should check the data in the new tables and verify that nothing went wrong before you drop the old table. (And please remember, the old table's name is `Old_Persons` now!)
- **Always backup your database and test your backup files before you start to modify your schema** (There is a guy called Murphy you know)
- The last join should be modified if any of the columns in the `New_Persons` table are nullable. You have to handle the `NULL` 'values'
- If there will be more normalization, consider to create a new database and migrate your data from the old one to the new one.

**Personal note**

I prefer to create entirely new tables with the required structure and constraints, and fill them with INSERT INTO ... SELECT statements. After the new tables are filled (and the data is verified) rename the old tables, then rename the new ones. The last step is to add the indexes to the new tables. The old tables could be archived after everything is working fine.

I hope, this helps. Happy coding :)

Ohh, and the [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba3d2/1)

Comment: Thanks @pred! I tried so many things that did not work and when I look at your answer I think "Why could I not think of this!"

Comment: Multiple GROUP BYs does the trick! Even though I got my answer, just a couple of things before I mark your answer as correct 1) I wanted the SQL for the NEW Person_Charities table that has 3 columns: Person_Id, Charity_Org_Id and Designation_Id, so please edit your answer 2) the link you have given for **Build your query based on a prev. query** should refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html, I think instead of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Comment: and I totally agree with your **Personal Note** :)

Comment: @Vetruvius: I'll update my answer as soon as possible (now, I have some work to do, so after that). I want to add more details, so please stay tuned :)